# Merge GitHub branches from Azure

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am setting up CI/CD at work and there is one step I’m not sure how to do and furthermore, if it is a right thing do.

For background, I am used to develop in C# with Visual Studio, source code in TFS and deploying with basic script that copies files on the intranet.

Now, I’m requested to setup Build and Release pipelines on Dot Net Core projects in GitHub.

I have three branches on this project: DEV, RELEASE and MASTER

I created one pipeline that triggers on DEV’s commits, creates an artefact and deploy to DEV server.
Those are the pipelines that deploy all developers work to a DEV server where they run their own tests.

Next step, when we want to deploy to staging servers, we click a button in Azure, this merge the DEV branch to the RELEASE branch but I know close to nothing in GitHub, not even sure those are the appropriate words.
When the merge is done, this will trigger a build pipeline that will create a different artefact, when this artefact is updated, deploy to staging server.

Once this release is validated on Staging and Quality, we would merge RELEASE to MASTER and do the same until PROD servers.  It is all on intranet and self-hosted agents.

Is that a good way of doing things?  Can it be done this way?  I need a PowerShell task or is there something that exists?

Comment: So are you using GitHub Actions for deployment or are you using Azure Pipelines? Where does GitHub fit into this? You need to explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail and explain what platforms you're trying to use for which pieces.

Comment: I'm not using GitHub Actions yet.  GitHub is the source code repo for now.  I am using Azure to setup the CI/CD.  I have a pipeline that deploy to DEV server.  We are using Windows Self -hosted agents, pipeline connects to GitHub, copy the code to the agent, build and store an artifact on Azure.  An Azure pipeline triggers on new version of artifacts, unzip the artifact to the agent and copy the files to intranet server. I want a pipeline that I can trigger manually that will move DEV branch to RELEASE branch and deploy to STAGING the same way as DEV but from RELEASE branch. Hope it is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Azure DevOps pipeline, the pipeline should select GitHub for repository type, then we can [configure the CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

**a**. Configure CI trigger:

Classic steps:

**1**.Open project setting->Service connections->select GitHub-> create a new GitHub service connection

**2**.Create a new build pipeline via classic editor-> Select GitHub as the source.

**3**.Open pipeline->select the tab Triggers-> enable the option Enable continuous integration and configure the Branch filters

**b**.YAML steps:

**1**.Open project setting->Service connections->select GitHub-> create a new GitHub service connection

**2**.Create a new build pipeline and select GitHub(YAML)

**c**.The sample of Check out GitHub repositories in your pipeline

```
    resources:
    
      repositories:
    
      - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    
        type: github
    
        endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    
        name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo

  

    trigger:

- {branch name}
```

Configure CD trigger:

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers) to configure the release trigger.

If you are using GitHub action.

Please select the correct  workflow to configure the CI/CD, Please refer this [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-positive-and-negative-patterns) for more details

CI sample:

```
on:

  push:

    branches:    

    - ' DEV'
```

**Update1**

When Dev branch is updated, it is built and deployed to Dev server by pipeline.

Create build A and release B, configure the CI build trigger, when the branch Dev is updated, it triggers the build pipeline A, and when build pipeline A is completed, it triggers the release pipeline B.

click a button to synchronize Dev branch to Release branch.

We cannot see the button, as a workaround, we can add task powershell and call the API to [create pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [complete the pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). We also can add task cmd and publish the code via git cmd

Comment: Thank you but I'm confused.  I have a GitHub connection, I used in my first pipeline that gets code from DEV branch, build and uploads an artifact.  A release pipeline uncompress the artifact and copy the binaries to DEV server.  In your explanation, I am searching where I can specify to merge DEV to RELEASE branches, once I can trigger this I guess it will be copy and paste to build the RELEASE version and copy binaries to STAGING server.  I must be missing something but I can't see.

Comment: You mean, when the Dev branch is updated, the code of the Dev branch is synchronized to the release branch through the pipeline, right?

Comment: No.  When Dev branch is updated, it is built and deployed to Dev server by pipeline but then, when scrum master is happy with Dev, he wants to click a button to synchronize Dev branch to Release branch.  Meanwhile I have found task but not working as I expected so I reverted to a script task with Git commands.  Thanks !